# open terminal on X window by apache + django

Tags: python, django, gnome-terminal

I am using apache + django(mod_wsgi) to do some job.

First, I write a simple bash script that will invoke terminal on X window,
and executing some command. ex:

`DISPLAY=:1 gnome-terminal -e 'sleep 9999' &`

If I run this command/script in ssh session, it keep alive even I logout ssh session.
However, if I execute this command in django python code. 
gnome-terminal will run and close immediately 
because its parent(apache session?) is exited?

How can I run such command(gnome-terminal -e 'cmd') by django + apache without kill it?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the first question is "are you sure you want to do this?"

How are you attempting to start the process? If you are calling `os.system` it definitely won't survive, but if you are calling `os.fork()` and then `os.execv` I'd think it would survive. But, if *that* doesn't work, I think you could follow the standard process for daemonizing, which should work.

That's something like:

```
fork()
in child, close open file descriptors
open stderr, stdout, stdin (read from dev/null, write to dev/null perhaps) 
setsid()
chdir('/')
fork()
in child, exec the terminal.
```

See the discussion here on daemonizing: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66012-fork-a-daemon-process-on-unix/